# What's wrong with this plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to create a plugin that would check if the controller/action is `/cont/act` and if so change it to `other/act` before it dispatches.

My plugin looks like this

```
class Plugin_Test extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'cont' &&
           $this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'act') {

           $this->getRequest()->setControllerName('other');
           $this->getRequest()->setActionName('act');

        }
    }
}
```

problem is this does not seem to work. I've registered the plugin and I see that it's being called

Comment: try `$request` instead of `$this->getRequest()`

Comment: like experimentx say , $request->setModuleName('blabla')
        ->setControllerName('other'))
        ->setActionName('act')
        ->setDispatched(false);

Comment: another thing to get the current action controller use $actionController = $this->getActionController();

Comment: @Haim Evgi: I'm pretty sure that `$this->getActionController()` won't work in a plugin, especially in `preDispatch()`. Practically speaking, the only places in the ZF dispatch cycle that have access to the actual controller _instance_ are in dispatcher (which creates the controller instance) and downstream objects like action helpers that are passed the controller instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Plugin_Test extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if($request->getControllerName() == 'cont' &&
           $request->getActionName() == 'act') {

           $request->setControllerName('other');
           // $request->setActionName('act'); <- not required 

        }
    }
}
```